# Override element_pre_render() function

Tags: hooks

I'm creating a module for drupal that needs to override some function on an existing module called Drag & Drop module from drupal.

The function `dragndrop_upload_element_element_pre_render` that needed to be overriden. But I haven't got any luck overriding it. Is there a way to do it?

Image below is the function that I want to edit.

[image]

Did some of these, of course would not work. Any solution for it?

- `dragndrop_upload_element_element_pre_render_alter($element)`
- `MODULE_dragndrop_upload_element_element_pre_render_alter($element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_element_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.4.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 *
 */
function mymodule_element_info_alter(&$types) {
  if (isset($types['myelement'])) {
    $types['myelement']['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_myelement_pre_render';
  }
}
```